# Behavior Control of Oscillators

Tags: classical-mechanics

I am looking for good resources where I can learn more about  designing  oscillators , so that I can choose how they should behave.

Like for example how should i choose c and m so that the eigenfrequency is so high , or for example how should I choose m and c so that they have negligible mechanical  effect on the system they are attached to.